# How to get the metadata in the Audio Stream for flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am building an application that uses flutter plugin assets_audio_player, And currently, I am getting the audio stream but I am unable to get the metadata from the stream(TimedMetaData). Is there any way I can get the metadata from the stream using any plugin? all the plugins I have searched provides metadata from local files, but none of them can get metadata from the URL. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) package to get the metadata of a file by its URI (or local path):

```
import 'package:flutter_ffmpeg/flutter_ffmpeg.dart';

final FlutterFFprobe _probe = new FlutterFFprobe();

_probe.getMediaInformation(fileURI).then((i) => print(i));
```

Comment: I have tried flutter_ffmpeg. It gives if the file is there but not stream. I want to get the stream metadata as it changes.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I am running into the same problem with flutter_ffmpeg.